# Possible arrangements of $n$ balls in $n$ boxes

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification

> Suppose that there are $n$ boxes labelled $1, 2, . . . , n$ and there are $n$ balls
> also labelled similarly. The balls are thrown into boxes completely
> randomly so that each box receives one ball.
> (a) How many possible arrangements of balls in boxes is possible?
> (b) Find the probability that the ball labelled $1$ goes into the box
> labelled $1$.
> (c) Find the probability that at least one ball is in the box with the
> same label.

Here is a solution..
(a) There are n balls that can be placed in $n$ boxes, so there are $n$ choices for the first ball, $n-1$ choices for the second ball, $n-2$ choices for the third ball, and so on. Therefore, the total number of possible arrangements of balls in boxes is $n!$, which is the product of all positive integers up to $n$.

(b) There are $n$ boxes, and each ball has an equal probability of landing in any of them. Therefore, the probability that the ball labelled $1$ goes into the box labelled $1$ is $\frac 1n$, since there is only one box labelled $1$ out of $n$ boxes, and each box has an equal probability of receiving the ball.

Please check my solution for $a$ and $b$ and please provide a possible solution or hint for finding $c$.

Comment: Please provide context with your solution verification questions.

Answer (score 1):

The first two parts are correctly done. For part $c$, we are just finding the number of possible *derangements* for $n$. You can find more about derangements of n here: https://brilliant.org/wiki/derangements/

Now for the problem we see that number of cases   in which any ball does not go to it's labelled box is,
$$D_n = n!(1-\frac{1}{1!}+\frac {1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!} ... \frac{1}{n!})$$
P($n_{th}$ ball does not go into $n_{th}$ box) = $$1-\dfrac{1}{1!}+\dfrac {1}{2!}-\dfrac{1}{3!} ... \dfrac{1}{n!}$$
P(at least one $n_{th}$ ball goes into $n_{th}$ box) =  $$1-(1-\dfrac{1}{1!}+\dfrac {1}{2!}-\dfrac{1}{3!} ... \dfrac{1}{n!})$$
$$=\dfrac{1}{1!}-\dfrac {1}{2!}+\dfrac{1}{3!} ... \dfrac{1}{n!}$$